# Checar se arquivo é mais recente e então fazer download

Tags: c#, arquivo, http-request, webrequest

Criei um serviço do windows, que diariamente faz o download de alguns arquivos.
Esses arquivos tem cerca de 2Gb (isso mesmo, dois gigabytes!).

O problema é que esses arquivos estão todos os dias disponíveis no site, mas são atualizados aleatoriamente semanalmente, ou seja, não posso determinar em que data esses arquivos são atualizados.

Os arquivos sempre tem o mesmo nome, logo a mesma url.

Como posso checar se o arquivo no site é mais novo que o arquivo que já baixei?

A intenção é não ficar baixando os arquivos sem necessidade.

Abaixo minha função de download :

```
 private void FazDownload(string fileUrlToDownload, string Saida)
    {
        WebRequest getRequest = WebRequest.Create(fileUrlToDownload);

        getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", CookieAutenticacao);
        try
        {
            using (WebResponse getResponse = getRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                log.Info("Fazendo download de " + fileUrlToDownload);

                string OutPutfileFullPath = Saida;

                #region Se não existir o diretório então cria o diretório.
                if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(OutPutfileFullPath)))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(OutPutfileFullPath));
                }
                #endregion

                using (var fileStream = File.Create(OutPutfileFullPath, 8092))
                {
                    getResponse.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(fileStream);//Download e escrita em arquivo.
                }

                log.Info(String.Format("Download de {0} realizado com sucesso e gravado em {1}.", fileUrlToDownload, OutPutfileFullPath));
            }
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException)
        {
            log.Warn("Arquivo não encontrado em " + fileUrlToDownload);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Não há alguma forma de você obter a HASH do arquivo e comparar com o que tem no pc do usuário?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você necessita fazer essa requisição sem obter o conteúdo do arquivo. 
Para isso você deve usar o verbo head do http.

> HEAD
>
> > Variação do GET em que o recurso não é retornado. É usado para obter metainformações por meio do cabeçalho da resposta, sem ter que recuperar todo o conteúdo.
> >     http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#HEAD

A operação a baixo checa se o arquivo foi alterado desde uma determinada data

```
 public bool Modificado(String url, DateTime desde)
 {
        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;            
        request.Method = "Head";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;      
        request.IfModifiedSince = desde;            
        using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            return response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.NotModified;
        }
 }
```

Você pode utilizar a última data de modificação do arquivo antigo para testar se houve alguma mudança.